# nextline spacing PS1

Tags: bash, command-prompt, prompt, ps1

So here is my current PS1

```
PS1="\u[\W]\$(__git_ps1) \t \$? \\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

[image]

Whenever the PS1 overflows onto the next line I get this weird spacing display whenever I type something. Whats even weirder is that I can't delete the typed words and when I do backspace it adds empty characters instead of deleting the previous characters.

Is there something missing from my PS1?

Comment: The only thing that looks slightly off is that you run `tput` when you define the prompt, not when you display it; maybe the value of `$TERM is different in the two contexts? Try escaping that `$` as well.

Comment: Yup! Removing the tput line fixed it. I had gotten this from http://bashrcgenerator.com/ which already put the tput there so I took it at face value